# Alertview action After navigate to next View controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have Two `Viewcontrollers`,
in first `ViewController` had a AddButton when i click Add button it's navigate to second `ViewController`, second `ViewController` had verify button. inside verify button-click i am performing some verifications after that it's navigate to my first `ViewController`. once it navigate my first `ViewController` am showing to the alert `ViewController` it's working, but when i click alerview action it's should navigate to third `ViewController`. i tried but its not navigated another `ViewController` when i click alretview Action OK button.
this is my code

```
Firstviewcontroller button in side

let lv = NAViewPresenter().otpViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(lv, animated: true)

In SecondView Controller inside Button,

self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
OpacityView.shared.showingPopupView(view: self)
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.stopTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func stopTimer() {
            OpacityView.shared.hidingPopupView()
            if (count >= 0){
                if(count == 0)
                {
                    self.addAlertViewAction()
                }
                count -= 1
            }
        }

func addAlertViewAction() {
           let alertController = UIAlertController(title:NAString().add_my_service(), message:NAString().addButtonloadViewMessage(), preferredStyle: .alert)
            // Create OK button
            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                let lv = NAViewPresenter().myDailyServicesVC()
                lv.fromAddMyDailyServicesVC = true
//                self.present(lv, animated: true, completion: nil)
               self.navigationController?.pushViewController(lv, animated: true)
            }
            alertController.addAction(OKAction)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Look like your `navigationController` is `nil`

Comment: @DharmeshKheni how can resolve this

Comment: can you print it and check weather it has a value or not?

Comment: problem is hear only  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(lv, animated: true) when i print   let lv = NAViewPresenter().myDailyServicesVC() getting the values

Comment: check by un-commenting self.present VC if it presents the myDailyServicesVC then your code is working fine, then check the navigationController it should not be nil

Comment: @mlatha can you share demo project?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil) if i am used this one only am getting alert view

Comment: @DharmeshKheni this my project link pls check it out https://pastebin.com/6RK1t1wf

Comment: Finally i got the output, thank u for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

In Second View Controller,

```
import UIKit

protocol CustomDelegate {

    func sendValues(withData : Any)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var popupView: PopupView!


    var delegate : CustomDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func popButtonAction() {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        delegate?.sendValues(withData: (Any).self)
    }
}
```